# What is the phonetic difference between "White House" and "white house"?

Tags: english, phonetics, prosody, stress

I guess this is really a difference of stress (though I confess, as a non-native, I barely perceive it).

- Obama lives in the White House (*white* has primary stress?)
- I live in the white house on this street.
- Whitehouse is the Chief Surgeon here. (Same as white house in sentence two?)

Comment: `Whitehouse` probably does not pronounce the `h` as such.

Comment: @Joop Eggen You mean the *h* in *house*?

Comment: So in American English, since the *h* goes away in Whitehouse, /t/ flaps because it is intervocalic.

Comment: Henry Lee Smith used to use that distinction to illustrate intonation and stress. _Not every white house is the White House_ was the example sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right to say that the difference between these is one of stress. "White House" has a single stress on the first syllable, "white house" has an equal stress on both syllables.

Linguistically the difference is that "White House" is a compound, while "white house" is an adjective-plus-noun phrase.

Comment: I agree. Maybe in *white house*, stress is a bit stronger on *house*.

Comment: This is actually the typical stress behaviour for compunds (stress on the first part of the compound) vs. adjective modified nouns (stress on both parts with tendency towards the noun, i.e. second part).

Comment: @lemontree. Yes, this is absolutely the typical stress pattern for English  compounds if both components are monosyllabic. If the components are polysyllabic there is typically a stress on each one of them.

Comment: I don’t agree that there is only a single stress in _White House_ – there is only a single _primary_ stress, yes, but _House_ still carries secondary (or perhaps tertiary) stress, too. That is the primary difference between the building _the White House_ and the name _Whitehouse_: the name really does have only one stressed syllable, with _-house_ being completely unstressed. Additionally, there is (usually) no pre-fortis clipping in _White-_ in the name, while there (often) is in _White House_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: This all depends on what you use the word "stress" for. Some phoneticians, such as [John Wells](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/09/emilio-marquez-writes-i-would-like-to.html), prefer to say that those kinds of syllables are unstressed, but have a "strong" or unreduced vowel, in contrast to unstressed syllables that contain reduced vowels (I assume that is the kind of pronunciation of "Whitehouse" that you are referring to? I'm not familiar with the name).

Comment: @brasstacks No, I wouldn’t reduce the vowel in the name _Whitehouse_ – it’s still /ˈwaɪt(h)aʊs/ with full vowels, the same stress pattern as Amy Winehouse or Jack Whitehall’s last names. But that is acoustically distinct from the _White House_ /ˈwaɪ(ʔ)t.ˌhaʊs/ˌ with secondary stress on _house_, and from a _white house_ /ˈwaɪʔt.ˈhaʊs/ with more or less equal stress on both syllables.

Answer (score 1):

It is a difference in stress, adjective 2white 1house versus compound 1white3house, but it's also a difference in rhythm.  The adjective 2 1 construction is 2 measures versus the 1 measure of the compound 1 3 noun:

```
o BA ma | LIVES in the | WHITEhouse  (3 measures for the compound)  
o BA ma | LIVES in the | WHITE | HOUSE (4 measures for the adjective)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers given are good. To reply to one of the comments above, the "h" is pronounced in both cases in American English;  it is a question of stress that determines the difference.  **wɑ́jt haws** vs.  **wɑjt háws**